# Indexing a large cached table causes hanging

Tags: hsqldb

I am creating a largish cached table.
It has 28031732 rows.
The db is a file.
I disconnect.
I reconnect.

Everything is fine and dandy.

I then index the table.

Everything is still fine and dandy.

I disconnect.

I have never successfully reconnected.

I am using hsqldb 2.3.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't happen if you shutdown the database after adding an index. If you get an error message report it.

Comment: No error messages. Nothing unusual in the logs.

Comment: adding `hsqldb.large_data=true`  appears to have fixed it. Hmmm.